# Linux module load

Tags: linux, drivers, kernel-modules

I have one question one of my Linux box which is RHEL 7.8 the module joydev is loaded on one server but not on the other server.

Server A => Module joydev is loaded successfully 
Server b => Module joydev is not loaded

I know I can load the module on server B but looking for root cause when both the system installation is some why the module loaded on one server but not on another.

Comment: What happens when you `modprobe joydev` on server B? If this results in an error, get more information from the message buffer `dmesg | tail`. If it succeeds, find out if `joydev` is loaded automatically on server A, for example using the kernel command line, or `/etc/modules-load.d`, or in the initial RAM filesystem.

Comment: Perhaps it might get loaded by some KVM (keyboard, video and mouse) set to this system?

Comment: May suggest you add informations about the joydev module so anyone can help with your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved
The joydev module is getting loaded automatically when we run the IDRAC/ILO virtual console, which means the IDRAC virtual console uses the joydev module.